# Chaging the font size of figure caption

Tags: graphics, captions, fontsize

I am using the command `\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}` in order to change the font size of the caption of my figures. This works fine if the caption goes over only one line. But if a caption is very long and goes over two lines, the font size of the second line remains unchanged. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{a}
A
\end{equation}
\begin{table}   
\centering   
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\linewidth}|}     
\hline A \\     \hline  
\end{tabular}   
\caption{This text here is in footnotesize as required. Now comes a reference \hyperref[a]{(\ref*{a})}}. Why is this text and the reference \hyperref[a]{(\ref*{a})} large? And why does LaTeX make the linebreak before the dot?
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That should not happen.  Can you provide a minimal working example which shows the problem.

Comment: Short test for your claim: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\linewidth}|}
    \hline
\lipsum[1]\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\lipsum[11]}\label{tab:lipsum}
\end{table}
\end{document}` . From it you will see, that while caption (5 lines long) has the same font size. Please provide similar test file, which reproduce your problem,

Comment: I know now what the problem is. The problem is that I am using something like `\hyperref[test]{(\ref*{test})}}` in the caption. If I delete this part, it would work fine.

Comment: I can't confirm your claim that `\hyperref[test]{(\ref*{test})}}` change caption font size. It works as expected, however, depends on your `hyperref` package settings, it can draw red box around reference which can give impression, that the reference is bigger. Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: please always provide a small but complete example that shows the problem. Whatever is causing your issue it is code not mentioned in your question, which makes it very hard to answer.

Comment: I have included now a minimal working example. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare caption content with document text, i.e. Your caption is finished immediately after command `\hyperref[a]{(\ref*{a})}`. Dot was already out of caption.

See:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,
               colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,
               urlcolor=blue]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{a}
A
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.9\linewidth}|}
\hline A \\     \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This text here is in \texttt{footnotesize} as required. Now comes a reference \hyperref[a]{(\ref*{a})}% <--- here was end of caption!!!
. Why is this text and the reference large? Because this part of text was not included in caption!}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `\hyperref[a]{(\ref*{a})}` doesn't change caption text font size.

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid mistake.

Comment: @mahu_83, it happens. Anyway, you can up-vote and even accept answer (by clicking on up-pen and check mark at top left side od answer) :-)